# Applying median filter in Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

Suppose I have an RDD of integers, how to apply a median filter to it if the window for the filter is 3?

All of the map and filter methods in Spark that I looked into, process only one element at a time. But to find the median within a window, we'd want to know the values of all the elements with in the window at the same time.

I am new to Spark, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found window functions and UDAFs in the Spark API to be a good way implementing the median filtering.

Registering a UDAF:

`sqlContext.udf().register("medianFilter", medianFilterUDAF);`

Calling a UDAF over a window:

`Column col1 = org.apache.spark.sql.functions.callUDF("medianFilter", intDF.col("column1")).over(Window.orderBy("columnA", "columnB").rowsBetween(-windowSize, windowSize));`

`medianFilterUDAF` is an object of a custom UDAF that performs median filtering of elements over a window. You have to override the methods of the UDAF class viz. `dataType()`, `evaluate(Row buffer)`, `initialize(MutableAggregationBuffer buffer)`, `update(MutableAggregationBuffer buffer, Row row)`, `merge(MutableAggregationBuffer buffer1, Row buffer2)`, `inputSchema()`, `bufferSchema()`, and `deterministic()`.

So for median filtering, you have to sort the elements of the buffer and return the middle element in the `evaluate` method.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need to apply median filter like one described in this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter) page.
It can be done, but it is not very efficient to do in Spark.

Basically you need to first make an RDD with the neighbours of `x_n`: `RDD[X_N] => RDD[List(X_N -1, X_N, X_N +1)]`. Here is my code that computes the very same example from Wikipedia. Sorry, it's in Scala, not in Java, but I suppose that idea should be clear.

```
val nums = List[Int](2, 80, 6, 3)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(nums, 2)

def median3(x: List[(Int, Int)]): Int = {
    // here we discard the index of x and sort by its value
    val x2 = x.map(_._1).sorted
    x2(1)
}

val filtered = rdd.zipWithIndex.flatMap{
        t =>
            val (x_n, n) = t
            // First, duplicate data: x_n should appear in windows of its neighbours
            List(
                (n - 1, (x_n, -1)), // the last value is kept for illustration
                (n, (x_n, 0)),
                (n + 1, (x_n, 1))
            )
    // grouping by n we will get (x_n-1, x_n, x_n +1)
    // flatMap to discard corner cases
    }.groupByKey().flatMap{
        r =>
            val (i, x) = r
            (i, x.toList) match {
                case (_, x) if x.size == 1 => None // corner cases: n=-1 and n=4
                // first element and last element need special treatment
                case (i, x) if i == 0 => Some((i, median3(List(x.head) ++ x)))
                case (i, x) if x.size == 2 => Some((i, median3(x ++ List(x.reverse.head))))
                // filtering itself
                case (_, x) => Some((i, median3(x)))
            }
    }.sortByKey().map(_._2).collect()
// filtered: Array[Int] = Array(2, 6, 6, 3)
```

This code is inefficient for 2 reasons:

- it uses 3x more memory (at least) for data duplication
- it performs at least 2 key shuffles (`.groupByKey` and `.sortByKey`), which is the most expensive operation in Spark

If by any chance your data fits onto one machine it is better to go with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_median.html) for instance.